# Dynamically make a clicked node as a parent of the loaded nodes - jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm new in jsTree and I have 2 questions.

**Explanation: **
I have jsTree of many hierarchies based on their ids and types and I'm trying to implement load on demand technique. On page load, I display only first hierarchy (root nodes) with no children. Then when I click on any of the node, I go and retrieve the children(in JSON format) of that particular node based on it's id and it's type. jsTree appends the hierarchies successfully on the browser but it fails to acknowledge that the clicked node is a parent of the loaded nodes (Logically I would expect this because I didn't tell jsTree to do so). So, now my questions come:-

1) How do I dynamically make this clicked node as a parent of those loaded nodes?.

2.) I have to double click on the node for jsTree to load the corresponding children. How do I do that in just a single click?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code code:

```
   In the Servlet, I have the following conditional statements:-

           if(type.equals("root"))
           {
            String jsonString = TreeTest.getRoot().getString("data");
            out.write(jsonString);
           }
           else if(type.equals("rig"))
           {
             String jsonString = TreeTest.getSecondHierarchy(Integer.parseInt(id)).getString("data");
             out.write(jsonString);
           }
           else if(type.equals("well"))
           {
             String jsonString = TreeTest.getThirdHierarchy(Integer.parseInt(id)).getString("data");
             out.write(jsonString);  
           }
```

The JSONObject which I am returning for every call is in the form of

"data": {
            "data" : "node_name",
             "attr": {"id": node_id,  "type" : "node_type"}
         }

---

```
        Here is my jsTree codes 

          $(document).ready(function(){

              $("#tree").jstree({

                     "themes": {"theme": "classic"},

                     "core" : { 
                            "strings" : { 
                              "loading" : "Loading data..." 
                            } 
                      },

                     "json_data": {


                     "ajax" : {
                      "type": 'GET',
                       "url": "TreeViewServlet",

                       "data": function(n)
                       { 
                        return{ 
                            "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0,
                            "type": n.attr? n.attr("type"): "root"
                        };

                       }

                    }
                   },


                "types" : {
                 "types" : {

                    "rig" : {
                        "icon" : {
                            "image" : "./images/Rig.gif"
                        }
                    },
                    "well" : {
                        "icon" : {
                            "image" : "./images/Well.gif"
                        }
                    },

                    "assysystype" : {
                        "icon" : {
                            "image" : "./images/whxt.gif"
                        }
                    },
                    "assy" : {
                        "icon" : {
                            "image" : "./images/Assy.gif"
                        }
                    },

                 "_Drl-WH" : {
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./images/w_icon.gif"
                    }
                },
                 "_Compl-XT" : {
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./images/x_icon.gif"
                    }
                },

                "subAssy" : {
                   "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./images/subass.gif"
                    }
                  }  
                }
              },
               "plugins" : ["themes","json_data","ui", "core", "types"]


            }).delegate(".jstree-open>a", "click.jstree", function(event)
                        {
                          $.jstree._reference(this).close_node(this,false,false);
                        }).delegate(".jstree-closed>a", "click.jstree", function(event)
                        {
                          $.jstree._reference(this).open_node(this,false,false);
                        });
                 });
```

Comment: post your code that you have tried

Comment: I have edited and added my code snippet @PragneshChauhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question and decided to post an answer:-

1) I had to get the ID of clicked node and send it to the Java Servlet, the Servlet then processes the request and returns a JSON string of all children of this node and then using AJAX, I append the children back to the tree.

2) There was a magic key, for every node, I added  `"state" : "closed"`  and that was it.